# Mailchimp form to pass in lightbox form plugin using functions instead of shortcodes

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

There are two WordPress plugins, one is form Form Lightbox plugin and other is MailChimp List Subscribe Form. Shortcode for form Lightbox is working as follow:

[formlightbox_call title="lightbox form" class="1322379893472"]Click here[/formlightbox_call] and 
[formlightbox_obj id="1322379893472" style="" onload="false"][form shortcode here][/formlightbox_obj]

And the shortcode for mailchimp is [mailchimpsf_form].
Now i have to open mailchimp form in lightbox popup on clickof "Click here" text. So it will become like this:

```
[formlightbox_call title="lightbox form" class="13223798934721"]Click here[/formlightbox_call]



[formlightbox_obj id="13223798934721" style="" onload="false"][mailchimpsf_form][/formlightbox_obj]
```

Above is working fine also. Here comes the problem:

If i have to so the same thing in php file using these plugin's functions:
1. formlightbox_call shortcode  is calling the below functions:

```
$a=array('title'=>"lightbox form", 'class'=>"1322379893472");
        echo fl_shortcode_call( $a,"Click here");
```

2. formlightbox_obj is caaling the below function

```
$b=array('id'=>"1322379893472", 'style'=>"", 'onload'=>"false");
        $e='Testing the code';
        echo fl_shortcode_obj($b,$e);?>
```

Above functions are also working, but I have to pass mailchimp form to the 2nd function that is having the problem.

Like this or please let me know some other way so it works:
    $b=array('id'=>"1322379893472", 'style'=>"", 'onload'=>"false");
            $e=;
            echo fl_shortcode_obj($b,$e);?>

This code is not working. Please help me to pass mailchimp formto lightbox using functions in PHP file.

Answer (score 0):

As mailchimp function is not returning any values, it is directly eching everything using ob_start() & ob_end_clean(). So i created new funciton of existing function but put the output in 1 varialbe and return the variable from function. So able to store the return of function in variable& use in lightbox.